# Converting Excel 2007 files to Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm currently using a library named http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelPackage>ExcelPackage to generate a large number of Excel files.

Unfortunately it saves in an xlsx format, the Excel 2007 OOXML format. I need it in the earlier 2003 .xls format, for my clients who tend to be somewhat technophobic when it comes to upgrading software. This basically means I can't make the end users use any sort of compatibility software like the official MS one. I can only convert the file, or use a completely different option, but it must result in a Excel 2003 readable file.

Is there any way I can either use another library to write it in the appropriate format, or find a library that will allow me to write autoshapes and the like directly into a 2003 format file? Using CarlosAg's http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/>ExcelXML method does not allow me to easily insert images.

---

In the end, I used http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/ to power the conversion to the earlier version. This library, while not free, was very simple to use and worked precisely as advertised.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: I love your icon. <3 Sinfest.

Comment: Your point about why the end user can't use the MS compatibilty pack doesn't really make sense. It works fine, requires zero effect/effort to use on their part and no training. Surely this is ideal for a "technophobic" type user?

Comment: As a clarification, the end users were teachers, and anyone who has worked IT in the education system can probably agree to the glacial movement of any upgrades in that environment =) Unfortunately, telling them "You must install <X> to work" wasn't an option available to us.

Answer (score 3):

Can you get them to install this ?

[Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint 2007 File Formats](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en)

This will let Office 2003 users open the newer file formats resulting from Office 2007. Works for the few documents I have tried.. before upgrading to 2007 :)

Comment: good call. this is all the 2003 users need. and it works fine with network and sharepoint resources.

Answer (score 1):

One option (if you have Excel 2007) is to do a "Save As..." and tell Excel to save it in the 2003 format.  This is probably the simplest route.

If you have a large number of files to convert (and it sounds like you do), then you may want to consider creating a script that makes use of Excel's automation features.  Then you can run the script to convert each file to the appropriate format.

Comment: nice idea +1.. as long as nothing gets lost during the 'Save As' process.. (e.g. ref something that is new in 2007)